# How to pass url parameters to the serializer in django rest framework

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am getting a com_id in the url later I want to valiate serializer now I dont know how to pass it to that serializer as the only data has been passed is what you get in the request methid here

```
class JoinCommitteeView(APIView):

    def post(self, request, com_id):
        data = request.data
        print('data', data, com_id)
        serializer = JoinCommitteeSerializer(data=data)
        
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
```

serilizer.py

```
 def create(self, validated_data):
        print('user_id', validated_data)
```

how to acess that com_id here so I can create the object here

Comment: You can include `com_id` in the serializer [`context`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context)